# null coalescing a JsonConvert in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json, razor

I have a script that looks like this

```
Item i = db.Items.Find(Model.ItemID);
Component comp = db.Components.Find(Model.ComponentID);

<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked(e) {
            var comp =  @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comp.ComponentID)) || null;         
            var item = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i.ItemID)) || null;           
            var compFSTK = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comp.FSTK)) || null;
            var itemFSTK = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i.FSTK)) || null;
            if (item == null) {
                alert('item is null');
            }
            if (comp == null) {
                alert('comp is null');
            }

                  if(comp != null && item == null) {
                      var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
                      var compDiff = @Model.comp_qty - compQty;
                      var compFuture = compFSTK - compDiff;
                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce component ' + comp.ComponentID + ' future stock to ' + compFuture))e.preventDefault();
                  }
                  else if(item!== null && comp == null ) {
                      var itemQty = $('#itemQTY').val();
                      var itemDiff = @Model.item_qty - itemQty;
                      var itemFuture = itemFSTK - itemDiff;
                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce item ' + item.ItemID + ' future stock to ' + itemFuture))e.preventDefault();
                  }
<script>
```

But whenever comp or i is null and is deserialized I receive the error of **'i/comp is null'**

how can I make it so that it just sets the variable to null if it is null?

Comment: I'm assuming the error is thrown at this line? `@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comp.ComponentID))`. If that's the case, doing `comp?.ComponentID` helps?

Comment: yes thats the error but I am usng C# 5 and it won't allow me to use what you suggested @devcrp

Comment: try @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comp==null?null:comp.ComponentID))

Comment: @Nigrimmist yes that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help ;)